# How to add multiple inputs under a single $key name

Tags: theme-development

I created a custom meta box in my wordpress theme and my codes are below. I want to create two types of $key names "ja_work_logo_url" and "ja_work_bg_images_url". The first one has only one input so it is straightforward and it is working with the code below. The problem is I would like to have multiple values under the $key names "ja_work_bg_images_url". I thought using [] after the key name and changing false from true with get_post_meta will do the job but it does not allow me to save the value.

Does anyone have any clue how to make it work?

I really appreciate all your help.

Best regards,

bigevent

```
    <?php

// work meta box Display Callback Start
function ja_work_meta_box_html( $post ) {
    ?>

        <p>
        <label for="ja_work_logo_url">Logo URL</label>
        <input name="ja_work_logo_url" id="ja_work_logo_url" class="postbox" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ja_work_logo_url', true ) ); ?>">
        </p>

        <p>
        <label for="ja_work_bg_images_url">Background Image URL</label></br>
        <input name="ja_work_bg_images_url[]" id="ja_work_bg_images_url[]" class="postbox" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ja_work_bg_images_url', false ) ); ?>">
        <input name="ja_work_bg_images_url[]" id="ja_work_bg_images_url[]" class="postbox" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ja_work_bg_images_url', false ) ); ?>">
        <input name="ja_work_bg_images_url[]" id="ja_work_bg_images_url[]" class="postbox" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ja_work_bg_images_url', false ) ); ?>">
        <input name="ja_work_bg_images_url[]" id="ja_work_bg_images_url[]" class="postbox" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ja_work_bg_images_url', false ) ); ?>">
   
        </p>


    <?php
}
// work meta box Display Callback End

//Save work meta box content Start
function save_ja_work_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {
        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
        if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
            $post_id = $parent_id;
        }
        $fields = [
                'ja_work_logo_url',
                'ja_work_bg_images_url',
        ];
        foreach ( $fields as $field ) {
                if ( array_key_exists( $field, $_POST ) ) {
                    update_post_meta( 
                        $post_id, 
                        $field, 
                        sanitize_text_field( $_POST[$field] ) );
                }
             }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_ja_work_meta_box_data' );
//Save work meta box content End
```